# Is there a way for tsc to list rootNames?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I was debugging a @typescript-eslint performance problem and found out (by adding `console.log('createProgram',rootNamesOrOptions.rootNames, rootNamesOrOptions.options)` to `createProgram` in node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js) that one of my `tsconfig.json` accidentally had `includes` that matched the `dist/` directory, causing too many files to be parsed by typescript.

Is there any official way for `tsc` to list all the root files that tsconfig.json matches so that you can sanity check them? I see [`--listFiles`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#listFiles), but that also lists all the recursively `import`ed files (e.g. in `node_modules`) so it is harder to look through.